# How to remedy a data conversion error in Azure Synapse Analytics when reading CSV a file

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

I've been following an [Azure analytics tutorial](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/DP-900T00A-Azure-Data-Fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/dp900-04-synapse-lab.html) and I'm trying to ingest a CSV file into an Azure Analytics Workspace. But when I try to group by a column in the SQL it throws an error. The SQL is this:

```
-- This is auto-generated code
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://daveslakestore.dfs.core.windows.net/daves-fs/products.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE
    ) AS [result];
```

and the error generated is:

`potential conversion error while reading VARCHAR column 'ProductName' from UTF8 encoded text. Change database collation to a UTF8 collation or specify explicit column schema in WITH clause and assign UTF8 collation to VARCHAR columns [etc]...`

I've determined the collation by executing:

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS Collation;`

which returns 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

I assume this should be UTF-8 not Latin and Googling
suggests this is a known error that requires me to
alter the collation, but I have been unable to see how.
I've tried without success to do the SQL below but I
don't know what my database name is, or even if
this is the right strategy?:

```
USE master;  
GO

ALTER DATABASE MyOptionsTest  
    COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 ;   --?
GO  
  
SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'MyOptionsTest';  —what should this really be?
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file probably hasn't a header row in Synapse. First see the columns:

```
-- This is auto-generated code
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://daveslakestore.dfs.core.windows.net/daves-fs/products.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

and give name to columns that you need:

```
-- This is auto-generated code
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://daveslakestore.dfs.core.windows.net/daves-fs/products.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) 
WITH(
    columnname1 INT 2,            --2nd column
    columnname2 VARCHAR(50) 5,    --5nd column
    columnname3 VARCHAR(50) 10    --10th column
)AS [result]
```

If you want to view with column header, don't change your code. Just go to file in synapse, right click-> preview-> with column header -ON -> OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading.
you missed the "GROUP BY Category;" as the last line in the SQL script.

The potential conversion errors are only warnings.
The real error line is at the end:
"Column 'result.Category' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

This indicates you forgot to Group by so that the select statement actually makes sense.

Set your script to:

```
SELECT
    Category, COUNT(*) AS ProductCount. 
FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://datalakexxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/files/product_data/products.csv',
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    PARSER_VERSION='2.0',
    HEADER_ROW = TRUE
) AS [result]
GROUP BY Category;
```

Please note the last line.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial [Azure analytics tutorial](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/DP-900T00A-Azure-Data-Fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/dp900-04-synapse-lab.html) , the file https://datalakexxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/files/product_data/products.csv does not have a header. The problem is, that without the header, when you set HEADER_ROW = TRUE, **the first row is taken as the header** and  collation conversion fails.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: With the row header selected the problem is still there. This does not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

we can use this code

```
SELECT
    [Category], -- Replace with the actual column name
    COUNT(*) AS ProductCount
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://datalakexxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/files/product_data/products.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIRSTROW = 2 -- Skip the first row as it's the header
    ) WITH (
        [Category] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS -- Specify a valid collation
    ) AS [result]
GROUP BY [Category];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the second line the cvs file is blank, and that is why setting HEADER_ROW=TRUE in the query would lead to retrieving to only one line, the header.  This got fixed when I removed the blank line. The issue of UTF collation persisted until I ran the query with the WITH clause as suggested above.  This then fixed all subsequent queries without WITH clause.